# [genxus]error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005)

Tags: genexus

Trabajo con:

- Genexus 17 U11
- Generador Java 1.8 Tomcat 9
- SqlserverExpress  2016

Desde hace unos tres días me reporta este mensaje de error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): No se
> puede ejecutar el programa. El comando que se estaba ejecutando era
> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /noconfig
> /fullpaths
> @"C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Temp\vg5m01pf\vg5m01pf.cmdline".
> ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): No se pudo completar la operaci¢n porque el archivo contiene un virus o software
> potencialmente no deseado